# Might and might have in the past

Tags: might

> I thought it **might help** her.

Why "might" and not "might have" since it's about the past?

Comment: Because it's *easier* to stick with simpler verb forms when more complex ones aren't necessary. It's not just a matter of adding "have", as implied by your question - the Perfect alternative also requires changing unmarked infinitive "help" to past participle "**helped**". Note that you haven't given a full context, anyway. If the speaker was talking about having an offer of help turned down in the PAST *for something that still lay in the FUTURE at time of utterance*, I imagine many speakers might say it would actually be logically / syntactically *invalid* to use the Perfect form.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at it as indirect speech. If you quoted your thoughts you would get:

- I thought 'it may help her'

Then, by leaving the quotation marks we often backshift the tense:

- I thought 'it may help her' -> I thought it might help her

You may also remember that when we talk about the past we often use past tenses even if we are talking about things that are still true:

- It's a shame that we moved out of Tokyo. It was such a nice place. (Tokyo still is a nice place)

Note also that 'might have' is not wrong in this case. It is used to say that it is possible that something happened, was true in the past or something was possible but did not happen

Comment: What If I want to still use " may'" then I should say I thought it may help her or it may have helped her?

Comment: "I thought it may help her" is ungrammatical for some speakers, just like ”I thought I can finish the book before I got home”.

Comment: @BillJ How can something be ungrammatical 'for some speakers'? English has rules for everyone although there are differences e.g. between British and American

Comment: @Samgra Both works but there is a difference in meaning

Comment: That's obviously not true. Here, it all boils down to Dialect A (older) vs Dialect B. For example, in Dialect A "I thought it may rain before we got home" is ungrammatical (just like ”I thought "I can finish the book before I got home”). "I thought it might rain before we got home is required". In Dialect B, both forms are possible.

Comment: @BillJ I have no idea what you mean by dialect A and dialect B. In modern English backshifting is not mandatory.

Comment: In Dialect B (the 'younger' one) there's no basis for retaining (from earlier stages of the language) the analysis of `might' as the preterite of “may”.  For those speakers, it must be a distinct lexeme, so it isn't substituted for "may" in backshifting. Never mind ...

Answer (score 0):

> I thought it might help her.
>
> I thought it might have helped her.

Both are grammatical.  The perfect version implies that "it" wasn't just an idea the speaker thought of, but something actually tried with the goal of helping her.

Comment: Is is also grammatical when we change might to may in both examples?

Comment: Some AmE speakers don't shift **may** to **might**  for past tense. Possibly the same is true of BrE.  For me **may** sounds  marginal there but others might hear it as ungrammatical.

Comment: I was taught that might is for the present and future and might have is for the past. Why i that might is allowed in the past without have?

Comment: I should say "in past contexts" not  "for past tense".  **might** is an auxiliary not the main verb in "I thought it might help", which would be understood as "At the time I thought there was a chance it would be helpful".  It refers to a prospective view situated in the past.  **I thought it might have helped** refers to a retrospective view situated in the past.

Comment: Now I get it thanks

Comment: So just might is more for telling a story and might have to for instance draw conclusions?

Comment: In your examples, the main clause **I thought** situates the thinking in the past. In one example, you are referring to an *expectation* held in the past; in the other example, you are referring to a tentative conclusion drawn in the past.

Comment: You explained the meaning of the first sentence At the time I thought there was a chance it would be helpful. Could you do the same with the second one?

Comment: At the time I thought there was a chance it had helped her.

Comment: What about this? I think she could have gone to work 2 days ago. Is it about drawing conclusions in the presence? We're not sure if that happened or not?And second I think she could work 2 days ago. It means that  shw was capable of working, had this ability? What happenes if we switch could to might and for example say I think she might work 2 days ago. Does it have any meaninng?

Comment: "I think she could have gone to work two days ago" is an expression of an opinion held now about her ability to go to work two days earlier: she was able to do so. "I think she might work two days ago" is ungrammatical.

Comment: What about she could go to work 2 days ago?

Comment: I thought I would win meaning At the time I thought there was a chance I would win. I thought I would have won meaning At the time I thought there was a chance I had won. Correct?

Comment: "She could go to work two days ago" is marginal but not ungrammatical, if the intended meaning is "She was able to go to work two days ago but she didn't go to work."

Comment: "I thought I would have won" seems  to refer to an envisioned contest where the speaker believed he would emerge as victor.

Comment: So no difference here? I think that on average this difference is realy subtle. Do you agree?

Comment: I thought it could rain meaning that it would rain and I thought it could have  rained meaning that it had rained correct?

Comment: *I thought it could have rained* means "At the time I had some reason to believe it had rained."  But there is no certainty.

Comment: Yeah I know thank you so much for help. This topic gives me some hard time and you explain it very well.

Comment: Do you know when for instance instead of saying she didn't let we can say she wouldn't let him. When changing didn't with would is fine?

Comment: *She did not let him finish his sentence.*  She interrupted him.  *She would not let him fiinish his sentence.*  **would** (past tense of **will**) can have the sense of repeated or habitual action, and so there is a strong suggestion that she interrupted him repeatedly, although that meaning is not entailed. But the construction is amenable to that meaning. For example, "I tried to explain but she *kept interrupting*  and would not let me finish my sentence."